# Rotating a Table and the caption

Tags: tables, captions, rotating

I used sidewaystable, as the table is very big. Latex is always turning the table in some way and I want it to be turn for 180 degree ( makes it easier to read, as it continues on the next page).

I tried this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaystable} [h]
\begin{turn} {180}
\captionof{table}{Overview of the handled studies.}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{turn}{180}
\end{sidewaystable}
\label{tab:methods_overview}
\end{center}
```

but I got this error:
! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.

If I use caption somewhere else, it turns the table, but not the caption.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Omit both the `center` and the `turn` environments, and place a `\centering` instruction before `\begin{tabular}{...}`.

If the tabular material should be rotated so that the bottom of the table ends up on the left, be sure to load the `rotating` package with the option `counterclockwise`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Overview of the handled studies.}
\label{tab:methods_overview}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
   \hline
   a & b & c & d \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now the head is looking to the left, but it should look to the right and thank you already.

Comment: @theresa_st - if you don't like the default orientation, be sure to specify the option `counterclockwise`.

Comment: @theresa - If you don't want to rotate a given table, don't use a `sidewaystable` environment to encase it; use `table` instead.

Comment: Ok I'll try to use table instead, but then the tabel still needs to be turned ( just the degree are changing) and the question is, how to do it, so that the caption is turned as well and no errors occur. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I managed it. I just wrote
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
so now all tables are looking to the same side and no turning is needed.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: @theresa_st - I infer from your latest comment that you use a document class that provides a two-sided page layout (different layouts for even- and odd-numbered pages). If this inference is correct, it would have been useful to provide this piece of information from the start. For sure, my divination skills are simply dreadful.